# How to detect Wi-Fi IP address changes in Android

Tags: android

Just wondering whether it's possible to detect IP address changes (Eg DHCP Lease expired) to the current connected Wi-Fi network?

Answer (score 1):

You can try listening for the `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcasts (see `WifiManager`). Those definitely should be broadcast if you switch to a new access point. Whether they get broadcast on a DHCP lease expiration, though, I can't say.